# Pattern Matching to select source file include/exclude NetBeans

Tags: regex, netbeans

I have source files in my project that i need to exclude. The unwanted files keeps the pattern `._namefile.java`. The NetBeans show me two fields to set the pattern:

Includes:

```
**
```

Excludes:

```
?
```

Thanks!

Comment: `*._namefile.java`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that adding an expression maybe similar to,

```
^.*\._namefile\.java$
```

in the `exclude` option might work, not sure though.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Rm170e/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Rm170e/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]